# How to format json reponse for autocomplete and make it linkable

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

Below is my coffee script for jquery autocomplete on `#search` bar.

```
jQuery ->
 $('#top_search #search').autocomplete
  source: $('#top_search #search').data('autocomplete-search')
  autoFocus: true
```

Above code is perfectly working and it renders all the results in json format as i am rendering in json from my controller like `render json: @searchResults`. But i want to make results as clickable similar to facebook search results.

Here in my case, it returns on text of matching user names as i am rendering JSON.
My question is, how to make that text bind to object such that i can click it ?

I am using `http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/` plugin in my rails using `//= require jquery.ui.all`

Comment: can you create a fiddle of your code ?

Comment: sure, can you meanwhile tell me whether how can we modify our json results in autocomplete response ?

Comment: Which `autocomplete` plugin are you using ? Please provide a link to it in your question.

Comment: @RahulGupta added the new info...is it sufficient ?

Comment: Do you want this ? http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/gN7pc/

Comment: Similar to that @RahulGupta, here i am render json from `@object` (table in database), and when it shows the suggested names when typing ..when i click on that suggested name .. i want to goto respective object location...am i clear ?

Comment: Sorry, but it is still unclear to me as what do you want exactly ! Please provide a snippet of your object which are you passing as data source to the autocomplete !